# How do variable references work?

Tags: ruby, variables

This is my code, nothing special:

```
server1 = @volume.pserver
puts server1
@volume.pserver = server2
puts server1
```

I expect that the reference itself, not the attributes of the reference, stored in `server1` always stays the same, but it changes:

```
#<Pserver:0x00000005bd3b98>
#<Pserver:0x0000000662b2a8>
```

How this is possible?

Comment: Can you tell, how you define `pserver` and `pserver=` methods of @volume object?

Comment: forget my comment, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I assume it's a bug in either rspec, factory_girl or mongoid. When I change the code as follows it works.

```
server1 = @volume.pserver.reload # no clue why reload is needed here
puts server1
@volume.pserver = server2
puts server1
```

I'm still puzzled what's the real cause. I'll try to make a simple project which reproduces the problem and post an issue to all three projects involved...